# How do I bind a checkbox in a REACT Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with an input and checkbox elements.  I am trying to bind the checkbox but it isn't working.  I am new to REACT and may be doing this an old way so please help me solve this before convincing me to try the new way.  You can share with me both.  That would be most beneficial to my learning.

Here's an except

```
handleMeetCheckBox(event){
 console.log(event.target.type)
 if (event.target.type === "checkbox"){      
   this.setState({[this.state.meet]:event.target.checked}) 
 } 
}
.
. 
.
render(){
return(
<div>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      name="meet" 
      checked={this.state.meet} 
      onChange={this.handleMeetCheckBox} 
    />
    Want to meet?<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="secret" />Secret?
    <p>If 'Secret' then....</p><br />
    Subject:<input type="text" name="subject"/><br /><br />
    Comments:<br /> <textarea name="comments" value=""  width="50"/>
    <hr />
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
  )
 }
}
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/mdejbvy)

Comment: Are you trying to set the value and the name of the input tag dynamically?

Comment: Yes I am but I get the error, checked undefined.  Just trying to grab the value of what was checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is in code at line

**this.setState({ [this.state.meet]: event.target.checked });**

the way the property is being set inside this.setState.

[this.state.meet] evaluates to "false", hence the state is set taking into consideration key as "false" and value as "event.target.checked",

change it to **this.setState({ meet: event.target.checked });**

and it will work, state changes as desired.

**Extra Explanation:**

if, 
  this.state = {
      meet: false,
      secret: false,
      subject: "",
      comments: "",
      **false:"x",
      true:"c"**
    };

and **this.setState({ [this.state.meet]: event.target.checked });** is used

after above line if you do console.log(this.state);

output will be

Object {
  comments: "",
  **false: true,**
  meet: false,
  secret: false,
  subject: "",
  **true: "c"**
}

thus changing the key computed via square brackets [this.state.meet]

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.  I made the change but when I click it nothing displays on line 78 of my codepen.  Any ideas?

Comment: try doing something like this, 
{this.state.meet && " yes"} <br />

true and false wont appear like that

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you are updating state you are setting the value to a different prop.`this.setState({[this.state.meet]:event.target.checked})`. By wrapping this.state.meet with brackets [] you are using the value of this.state.meet as the prop name, in this case "false", and not "meet".

You should be fine without the brackets `this.setState({meet:event.target.checked})`

Answer (score 1):

```
handleMeetCheckBox (event) {
  const { value, name } = event.target;
  this.setState({[name]: value})
}

printState () {
  console.log(this.state);
}


render(){
  return(
     <div>
        <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="meet" 
        checked={this.state.meet} 
        onChange={this.handleMeetCheckBox} 
        />

       Want to meet?<br />

       <input type="checkbox" name="secret" onChange=
        { this.handleMeetCheckBox} />

       Secret?

       <p>If 'Secret' then....</p><br />

       Subject:<input type="text" name="subject" onChange= 
              {this.handleMeetCheckBox}/><br /><br />

       Comments:<br /> <textarea name="comments" value=""  width="50"
           onChange={this.handleMeetCheckBox}/>

       <hr />

       <button type="button" onClick={this.printState}>Submit</button>
   </div>
        )
      }
     }
```